# How can I determine the time to send the message

Tags: discord.js

How can I set the duration of the message Example:

```
if (message.content === 'test') {
  message.channel.send (`he say test in 22seconds`)
}
```

Comment: You mean, the time for the bot to receive the message? Or you want to reply to the message after 22 seconds?

Comment: the time for the bot to receive the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the time it took to the bot to receive the message, use:

```js
if (message.content === 'test') {
  const seconds = ((Date.now()-message.createdTimestamp)/1000).toFixed(2);
  message.channel.send (`he say test in ${seconds} seconds`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function.

```js
if (message.content === 'test') {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
         message.channel.send (`it took me 22seconds to send this message.`); 
     }, 22000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. the question is not too clear but I'm guessing you mean once the user types a command, the bot says something and then the user can reply with `test` and the bot tells you how long it took you to type `test`? (Give the code a try and if its not what you wanted you can take parts out. :) )

The code:

```
const prefix = ''; //Put whatever prefix you want in the `(prefix goes here)`
var intervals;

bot.on("message", msg => {
  let args = msg.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  switch (args[0]) {
    case "test": // You can call the command whatever you want
      let timer = 3;
      msg.channel.send("Get ready").then(msg => {
        intervals = setInterval(function() {
          msg.edit(`Type test in the chat in **${timer--}**..`);
        }, 1000);
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(intervals);
        msg.channel
          .send(`Type test in the chat`)
          .then(() => {
            const time = Date.now();
            msg.channel
              .awaitMessages(
                function(userMsg) {
                  if (userMsg.content === "test") return true;
                },
                {
                  max: 1,
                  time: 10000,
                  errors: ["time"]
                }
              )
              .then(function(collected) {
                const endTime = Date.now();
                let successMsg = "Congratulations!\n";
                let collectedArr = Array.from(collected.values());
                for (let msg of collectedArr) {
                  let timeDiff = (endTime - msg.createdTimestamp) / 100;

                  successMsg += `You took ${timeDiff} seconds to type test.\n`;
                }
                msg.channel.send(successMsg);
              })
              .catch(function(collected) {
                msg.channel.send(`You did not answer in time!`);
              });
          })
          .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }, 5000);
      break;
  }
});
```

I'm not too sure what you're asking for but hope this is it! Again, give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you need the bot to send that message in 22 seconds. If thats the case then do this

```js
if (message.content === 'test') {

    setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout function dalays code inside of it for a set period of time

      message.channel.send (`he say test in 22seconds`); // Your code

    }, 22000); // The amount of time it should be delayed for. 22000 (milliseconds) = 22 seconds

}
```